# How to batch database modifications from SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm struggling to figure out how to batch modifications to our databases in SQL Server Management Studio. We'll perform actions like editing columns, creating tables, renaming tables, etc. that we need to perform on all of our environments - but not until we're ready to push the application. I'm trying to use the SQL profiler to grab the SQL but this seems horribly inefficient.

Is there a solution built into the application that will track such changes for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found my answer: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1723/auto-generate-change-scripts-in-sql-server-management-studio-ssms-for-tables/

Answer (score 0):

you can easily create scripts using the [osql utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214012%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) if you are on a version lower than SqlServer 2005.

From sql server 2005 onwards we use [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

Comment: Actually: starting with SQL Server 2005, you should use the [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) utility; isql/osql are deprecated